# How to add/show custom template in Create New Project screen while creating a new project?

Tags: android-studio

I have created my custom template and I need to add/show that in the initial screen while creating the new project.

I have added the custom template path as below:

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates/other/MyTemplate
```

With the above path, I can see my custom template in the project.

SO If I want to set my template in the first screen while creating a project then how can I set that?

I have tried to set the path as below for it:

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates/activities/MyTemplate
```

Comment: Hay i am doing same thing... and face same issue ? Have you solve this issue?

Comment: NO, I didn't get any solution yet to show the template on the first screen. @MehulKabaria